# changing git comment of a pushed commit

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to change the comment of a particular old(not latest/one behind) commit which is already pushed to the remote repository in git? There are no changes in the content of the commit. I only need to change the comment which I made which is a total error!

Thanks

Comment: Have other people already pulled from your repo? If not you could rebase and do a `git push --force`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to if it's not the latest push.  [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in git (I've pushed)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457379/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git-ive-pushed)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two ways to resolve your problem :

*> If your pushed commit is the last on your branch*

Remove your remote branch,  "git reset --soft HEAD~1", commit with your new message, and push your branch again.

*> If your pushed is in the middle of the branch*

Remove  your remote branch, "git rebase -i " where  is your commit place, choose "edit" for your commit, and push your branch again.

Remove/Create remote branch is very tricky... So take care to prevent your team first ;)