# How can I delete(or hide) a git commit from Sourceforge?

Tags: git, sourceforge

I have a project to which I commit almost daily and I would like to delete a commit from around 4 days ago, so that it would appear that the commit after that one was made immediately after the commit before it. The problem is a silly comment that is not very professional and that I wouldn't like to be seen (but now it can be seen very clearly with the diff feature of Sourceforge).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-to-delete-a-git-commit?rq=1 also the not accepted answers

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457379/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git-ive-pushed

Answer (score 2):

If the change has already been pushed (i.e. not in your local branch) then you might want to just forget about it. Because git is a distributed software configuration management tool, others may have pulled your changes and could potentially revert anything you try and undo. From the linked question above it is explained rather well:

> However, if others may have pulled it, then you would be better off
> starting a new branch. Because when they pull, it will just merge it
> into their work, and you will get it pushed back up again.
>
> If you already pushed, it may be better to use git revert, to create a "mirror image" commit that will undo the changes. However,
> both commits will both be in the log.

In general, making deletions on `origin/master` kind of goes against the whole idea of source control. You should be tracking all code, the good & bad.