# How can I push git-replace to a remote repo?

Tags: git

I have used "git replace" to substitute a branch (with no common ancestor) 22b2b25 for a commit in master.  I want this change to be permanent.  I'm not interested in the previous history.  In the output below the top five commits are from the original master branch and the bottom 2 come from a different branch.

When I pushed this to a new repository the git-replace was lost and the old history reappeared.  Is there a way to make this change permanent?

branch master looks like the below in the original repo.  I want to see this in the remote repo and subsequent clones.

```
[mike@localhost canal_site]$ git log --oneline --decorate
cdf0ae3 (HEAD, origin/master, master) MM: sqlencode course name for ad-hoc courses
2b57df5 MM: fixes for changes so far
7916eaf MM: ad hoc - more refactoring
1e00d22 MM: reformatted code
e36cee1 factored out equal ops
22b2b25 (origin/prod20140313, prod20140313) initial load from production 9-June-2015
08379cd initial inclusion of production files from 9-June-2015
```

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the reformatting and up vote.  I rather thought it was the use of the code stuff for non-code that had upset somebody but a -1 kills your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`git replace`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) alone isn't enough: replacing one commit isn't enough.

The next commit must now reference the replaced commit as a parent.

As mentioned in "[Removing a whole bunch of commits from git](http://www.kingsware.de/2014/07/29/removing-a-whole-bunch-of-commits-from-git/)":

> Backup your repo via git clone.
>   **Find out the first commit you do like after the commits you do not like** and remember the hash of its direct ancestor (in the following `bbb`).
>   Then find the first commit you do like before the commits you do not like (in the following `aaa`):

```
git replace bbb aaa
```

> Take a look at your repository (with `git log`) and check whether everything is as it should be after your intended change.
>   But the `replace` command just adds some meta information into `.git/refs/replace`, which git commands interpret correspondingly.
>   In order to make these changes permanent, you may use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

Then you would need to force push (git push --force) in order to override the remote repo with the new history of the branch. Or you van just push to a new empty bare repo.

---

Update (inspired from [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1246387/stephen)'s comment)

As I noted in Oct. 2019 in "[Git commands that could break/rewrite the history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)", git filter-branch or BFG are obsolete.
[`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is easier to use and more efficient.

Comment: `git-filter-branch` is outdated now, and the documentation suggests using `git filter-repo` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch  `git filter-repo --force` worked for me.

Comment: @Stephen Thank you. I have updated this old answer accordingly. I did notice `git filter-repo` in my 2019 answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309.