# Is there any way to edit github commit online that is committed recently?

Tags: github, comments, edit, commit

I have typo in my recent commit and I would like to change this immediately. In this situation is there an easy way to edit the commit?

Comment: https://github.com/Yugendhar/SecureGameCockNetwork/commit/d970138f2604ce52e7f3d9106629804b6c5c1621 . There is a typo in comment . I supposed to write "Registration"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in git (I've pushed)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457379/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git-ive-pushed)

Comment: Note that changing the commit message of a pushed commit requires rewriting the history, which is generally a bad idea on main branches. Also see https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/

Comment: This is possible in TFS and other VSTS integrated with Git but not in github commit