# How to back up private branches in git

Tags: git, merge, workflow, rebase, dropbox

I have a local branch for day-to-day dev work in git. My workflow is:

1. Do stuff on local_branch, commit
2. Fetch origin/master
3. Rebase local_branch to catch up with new stuff from origin/master

It all works fine, however most of the recommendations I encountered say that one should not "push" private branches, on which rebase is regularly performed.

The problem here is that in this case local branch is not backed up to a server and the only way to save the work is to merge it back to "pushable" branch (i.e. origin/master)

What would be your recommendations on the workflow in this case?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I realised that one of the original requirements I had (avoiding usage of external utilities) is unnecessary limiting.

My current solution is to store all my repositories in a cloud-synchronised folder - this   way I get backup for free.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I use the --mirror option and push to a personal backup repository:

Add it as a remote:

```
git remote add bak server:/path/to/backup/repo
```

Do the backup:

```
git push --mirror bak
```

This will automatically make your backup repository look like your active one -- branches will be created, deleted, updated (even forced/non-fastforwards) as needed.  You can make an alias for this too:

```
git config alias.bak "push --mirror bak"
```

Then, it's just a matter of running "git bak" when you want to do a backup.  You could also throw this into a cron job.

Comment: Thanks for --mirror and config alias, will look into it

Comment: Just a heads up, this will *not* mirror your configuration files from your `.git` directory (`config`, `hooks/*`, etc.).  Just a heads up.  Still, I think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with pushing personal branches. It is generally discouraged because people might start work based on your branch, and when you rebase, their changes are left floating.

What I do is use a prefix to denote "this is my branch, use it on your own risk", like: **fc-general-cleanup**.

Comment: But then after the rebase you get a warning of diverging branches, don't you? See http://superuser.com/q/667146/57249 . Is it possible that the solution is to do a `git push --force` for the private branch?

Comment: Of course you get a warning about divergence, that's what a rebase does, and yes, you need to do `git push --force`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to push "local_branch" to the "origin" repo, but to it's own branch in that repo (not "master"), i.e.:

`git push origin local_branch:local_backup`

Then when you are ready to make another backup (and after you've been doing some work and rebasing) just delete the backup branch from the origin repo before you push it out again:

`git push origin :local_backup`               <=== deletes the branch from origin

`git push origin local_branch:local_backup`

This way you won't run into problems pushing "local_branch" after it has been rebased from "origin/master".

And if deleting your backup branches makes you nervous (until after you've finally committed your work to "master"), you could always keep pushing to a new branch with a new name (e.g. "local_backup1", "local_backup2", etc).

Comment: would deletion be an unnecessary step if one uses push --force?

Comment: Yes, --force is a good alternative to deletion. It will replace the remote branch head with the new one from your local branch.

Comment: By default, remote repositories will reject non-fast forwards so --force may not be enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo/255080#255080

Comment: @Charles: That's exactly what the --force flag is for: bypassing git's default refusal to accept a non-fast-forwarding push.

Comment: No. The force flag is not - and should not be - for overriding the remote repository's behaviour of rejecting non-fastforward push attempts when receive.denyNonFastForwards is set. In these cases the only user-observable difference that --force will give is changing the error message from '[rejected]' to '[remote rejected]'.

Comment: Right, but it *is* for forcing fast-forwards when receive.denyNonFastForwards is *not* set. It is not set by default, except for "shared" repositories (which are also not created by default). Notice that I said "git's default refusal". If you add "receive.denyNonFastForwards" to your configuration, you are telling git to not allow non-fast-forwards even when forced.

Comment: @Charles: Just thought I'd add, for clarity, in case you didn't get this already, that git will deny non-fast-forward pushes even without the "receive.denyNonFastForwards" configuration variable set (unless forced, of course).

Comment: I get it, I just wanted to make sure that we documented that '--force' isn't sufficient in all cases. Most central repositories are be created as 'shared' (it's the simplest way to set up a multi-user enabled shared repository), hence my original comment that *remote repositories* will reject non-fast forwards which you appeared to contradict. I suppose I could have expanded on 'by default' a bit more, but I thought that my linked answer had a clear enough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Can you set up another remote repository that you do push all of your branches to? The other thing to consider is just backing up everything (important) on your local machine, including the git repo.

Comment: In case of setting up separate repository I'll still have a problem of changed history - i.e. I won't be able to push straight after rebase

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with pushing to the same branch that you are rebasing from. These diagrams should illustrate why this works fine:

Lets say this is what the commit graph looks like after you've branched local_branch and made a couple of commits to it (C and D). Someone else has made one commit (E) to origin/master since you branched local_branch:

```
A -- B -- E  [origin/master]
      \
       \    
        \-- C -- D  [local_branch]
```

Then after running "git rebase origin/master", the commit graph will look like the next diagram. "origin/master" is still the same, but "local_branch" has been rebased:

```
A -- B -- E  [origin/master]
           \
            \
             \-- C -- D  [local_branch]
```

At this stage, if you do "git push origin local_branch:master", then it will result in a simple fast-forward. "origin/master" and "local_branch" will be identical:

```
A -- B -- E -- C -- D  [origin/master],[local_branch]
```

Now you are free to do more work on "local_branch". Eventually you might get something like this:

```
A -- B -- E -- C -- D -- G -- I [origin/master]
                     \
                      \
                       \-- F -- H [local_branch]
```

Notice this looks a lot like the starting graph. You can keep repeating this process over and over.

You should avoid pushing to some *other* branch, one that you are not rebasing from. That is where you will run into trouble (to the other branch, it will look like your "local_branch's" history has suddenly been re-written, after you've rebased from "origin/master").

Comment: This is not quite what I want. Suppose the work is in progress and I don't want to merge it into master and just want to backup it.

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood your question. Sorry about that. It seems to me that a reasonable solution would be to clone your local repository to some location that *is* backed up. Just periodically re-clone to keep your backup up-to-date. But you don't necessarily need to do any work in the clone (you can just delete it before you re-clone to make a new backup).

Comment: @Dan, is this the workflow you would get when doing "git pull --rebase"?

Comment: @Casey: Yes. Normally 'git pull' is equivalent to 'git fetch' followed by a 'git merge'. But 'git pull --rebase' is equivalent to 'git fetch' followed by 'git rebase', and it results in the kind of workflow described above.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's what I do](http://coders-log.blogspot.com/2009/05/creating-remote-branch-with-git.html).  But - this isn't private.  I do this so that I can collaborate with myself (so to speak).  It lets me work on the same branch on two or more boxes.  if other people had access to the shared repo, they could see the work I'm doing on the branch.  Of course, on my home repos, nobody else has access, so it's still private.  On github, all the world could see my stuff.  Like they really care.  ;)

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any rebases, which is the actual problem I have.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to "git pull" your local copy then rebase locally?  Then your local branch would have all the changes from master merged in, and the next push would push to the remote branch.  I would have to try this to know for sure, but it seems like that would work.

Comment: Don, next pull after rebase on non private branch causes a conflict.

Comment: Hmm.  What's the conflict?  Was it the classic case of separate changes made to the same code block on separate branches?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on Dropbox to synchronize *all* the files of a git repo, I would rather use **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo/1251717#1251717)**, which produces only *one* file (including all your private branches), and sync that file with DropBox.
See "[Git with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox/3633346#3633346)"

In "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository/2129286#2129286)", [Yars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8047/yar) mentioned having sync errors with Dropbox.