# how to recover an accidently deleted remote git repository from local repository

Tags: git

I've done something like following:

(1) clone a remote git repository to local host

local# `git clone http://www.foo.com foo`

(2) add another project on a ssh host(bar) as the second remote repository

local# `git remote add bar ssh://bar/home/project`

local# `git fetch bar`

(3) done something stupid on the ssh host(bar):

bar# `rm -rf /home/project`

Could you please tell me how can I recover project on the ssh host(bar) from my local copy, so other developer on the ssh host can continue their work, and I can run 'git fetch bar' to get their commit, just like I didn't do anything wrong to their ssh host, i.e. undo all I did to host bar. thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

bar# `mkdir -p /home/project && cd /home/project && git init --bare`

local# `git branch remote show bar`

local# `git push bar bar/master:refs/heads/master`

local# `git push bar bar/branch1:refs/heads/branch1`

local# `git push bar bar/branch2:refs/heads/branch2`

Comment: If you have solved the problem, put the commands in a new answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can setup the remote host as a new git repository and then push to it.

This blog goes over how to do it:

[Toolman Tim - Setting up a new remote git repository](http://toolmantim.com/articles/setting_up_a_new_remote_git_repository)

assuming you still have bar setup as a remote repository, essentially:

```
ssh bar "mkdir -p /home/project && cd /home/project && git --init bare"
git push bar refspec
```

*refspec* is frequently just the simple name of the branch in the local repository so:

```
git push bar master
```

See the [git push manpage](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for a detailed treatment of what qualifies for a refspec.  The EXAMPLES section is particularly helpful in understanding more advanced respecs

Comment: thanks but I can't make it work: 

local# ssh bar "mkdir -p /home/project && cd /home/project && git init --bare" 

local# git push bar 

No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing. Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://bar/home/project'

Comment: that's why I referenced the blog which went much more in depth and used the word "essentially".  I will make my code sample more explicit so as to make the answer complete.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of one of these:

```
$ git push bar bar/branchX:refs/heads/branchX
```

for every ref'd branch in local. Try this

```
$ git push bar refs/remotes/bar/*:refs/heads/*
```

The above command should push all the remote refs you had cached locally back to the remote and put them in the right spot.

Note that you also need to push any tags you might have had:

```
$ git push --tags bar
```

Also, it helps to know what's going to happen before you actually do the push:

```
$ git push --dry-run ...(rest of push cmd)
```

NOTE: I used 'bar' where most people would have 'origin' - replace with the name of your remote.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Mark Carey's answer, I've particaly recovered the deleted repository as following:

bar# `mkdir -p /home/project && cd /home/project && git init --bare`

local# `git branch remote show bar`

local# `git push bar bar/master:refs/heads/master`

local# `git push bar bar/branch1:refs/heads/branch1`

local# `git push bar bar/branch2:refs/heads/branch2`

**UPDATE:**

[How to back up private branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923956/how-to-back-up-private-branches-in-git)

Comment: "Follow Mark Carey's answer"... if my answer was the "correct" answer then would it not be appropriate to award it "Answer" status.