# What version control system should I use?

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

I'm working by myself on a project.  I'd like an easy to use, free, version control system that integrates with IntelliJ IDEA nicely.  I'd prefer if the whole repository was isolated to a single file, or folder, so that I could back it up on a USB stick easily and transfer it to another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Git](http://git-scm.com/). The whole repository is in the `.git` directory under your project root (by default) and I believe IntelliJ IDEA just integrated Git functionality recently.

Assuming you are going with the default (having the `.git` directory in the project root), then you can just copy your project to a USB stick and you have your project and repository to go.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the various [IntelliJ IDEA VCS support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html), the one for **[git](http://git-scm.com/)** is fine and easy to use.

Plus, with **[`git bundle`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html)**, you can export your repo to *one* file, very easy to copy around (on a backup storage for instance).

See the SO question "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository)"