# Can I place .git somewhere else?

Tags: git

I'd like to use git for backups, but using more than double the space for `.git` is a bit too much. Is there a nice parameter that places the data somewhere else or do I have to mount my backup HD to `.git`?

Comment: If you plan on using Git for backups, consider using [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `GIT_DIR` environment variable in order to put your .git in another place than your current working tree.

From [Git man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git):

```
--git-dir=<path>
```

> Set the path to the repository. This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

Note that you will find valid alternatives for [backing up a Git repo in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository) (not including the [bup system](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup) mentioned by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) in the comments, python-based, which stores its data in a git-formatted repository).

Comment: @GregHewgill: Argh, I can't believe I managed to mess up your name, sorry.