# Keep 2 remote repositories always in sync

Tags: git, github

I have an organization account in github with a repository called A.
As github provides poor ACL for users, I would like to have an another repository called B that is in sync with repository A.

Repository B must also:

- have all branches in sync with A.
- have all the commit history of A

Basically, the repository B must be a backup of A.

I need this because I need to set different ACLs on Repository B.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

update:
i have tried this:

```
git clone B
git remote add upstream A
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

and this actually works: the master in B is in sync with the master in A, but I have no idea on how to accomplish this with branches present in A.

Comment: Via `push`ing and `pull`ing.

Comment: i have update the question to clarify where i'm stuck

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you're saying "the repository B must be a backup of A", I'm assuming that B is read-only. If so, you might want to use a "mirror" for this. I.e. set up your B repo like this:

```
git clone --mirror A
```

and then

```
git remote update
```

whenever you need to update B.

A couple of notes though:

- Commits to B, if any, will be lost when the update is performed.
- As the KDE project recently tought us, the mirror is [too perfect](http://jefferai.org/2013/03/24/too-perfect-a-mirror/). So if A somehow becomes corrupt, then B might mirror the corruption as well... For backup purposes, you might want to look into the answer to this question: [Backup a local git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository).

Comment: sorry, but can you be more clear in what git commands i need to use? after running `git clone --mirror` i don't get a working copy. instead it downloads a folder named a.git.  how can I add B as a remote? and use `git remote update?`

Comment: Both commands are executed on the server for the mirrored repositories. The first creates a bare mirrored repo. It 'knows' that it is a mirror and where the original is located. The second command updates the bare mirrored repo. To get a working copy, you must clone the mirrored B repo in the same fashion that you clone your original repo.

Comment: The question asked about "2 remote repositories" -- the assumption here is that you can't just run commands on the server (in this case github)