# When to use --keep-cr with am and in which version of git it got introduced?

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf, format-patch, git-am

I am trying to formalize a patch workflow for our org. We have an internal project where we don't mind white-spaces(would like to keep them same for each user if possible), EOF/EOL characters etc. We have developers working on both Mac and Windows platform. AT both places we use git with Cygwin.

I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140604/problems-with-git-format-patch-am-patch-does-not-apply) that core.autocrlf true does the trick or you can use `--keep-cr`.
But [here VonC suggests `core.autocrlf` false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git?lq=1) is a better strategy.

My Questions are:

1. When to use true and when false? (I just don't want git to bug me
   and patches should apply smooth).
2. When was `--keep-cr` introduced? I use git 1.7.2 and am man page does not have this option?
3. What Ignore-whitespace options to use so as to have smooth patch workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.7.2 should have `--keep-cr` for git am, since it was introduced in [commit ad2c928](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad2c928001d2d94f2cbf3c75734061eb8fc4383c) by Stefan-W. Hahn, included in Git 1.7.1.

> when you know you are feeding output from "`git format-patch`" directly to "`git am`", and especially when your contents have CR at the end of line, such stripping is undesirable.  To help such a use case, teach `--keep-cr` option to "[`git am`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)" and pass that to "[`git mailinfo`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mailinfo)".

However, on Windows, I always use the [latest Git For Windows release](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases), [not the cygwin one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309) (even though [you can have both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702140/6309)).

The issue with [`core.autocrlf` is that it is a repository-wide setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/6309) which can affect *all* files (even non-text ones).
I prefer [`core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309).

For whitespace, you can try "[git: patch does not apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832785/6309)":

```
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace mychanges.patch
```

Comment: What is the difference between apply and am. Coz I have noticed some patches apply seamlessly using apply but create problem on using am.

Comment: @MudassirRazvi Git am is more for patches coming from mails

Comment: That brings to my next question. What difference does it make? I create patch using format-patch. Send it to my colleague via Outlook. he downloads and applies patch using am.

Anything wrong here?

Comment: @MudassirRazvi nothing wrong, the end result is the same. I will have more when I get back (I am outside, typing from my phone)

Comment: Will be waiting..! :)

Comment: @MudassirRazvi for more on the difference between am and apply: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12240154/6309. http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html is a good read: I like communicating patches through bundle  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16407577/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24075658/6309)