# Cannot copy .git folder via usb stockage

Tags: git

I have a folder F containing a .git folder on my machine A. I connect my phone to the machine A, and copy the folder F on my machine. The copy seems going well: I have on my phone memory the folder F with its content.

But when I try to access to the folder F after unplugging my phone, the folder F is empty, the `.git` folder is not present anymore, and whatever the machine on which I try to access my phone memory, the folder F is empty.

Is there a way to copy a `.git` folder via my phone memory?

Comment: How do you look at the folder F after you've copied it to your phone?

Comment: Is it possible that you are not seeing the .git folder because it starts with a dot and is hidden by default in the file browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

> whatever the machine on which I try to access my phone memory, the folder F is empty.

Try and access `<usb_drive_letter>:F\.git` after copying.
Validate that the repo is there with:

```
cd <usb_drive_letter>:F\.git`
git log
```

But another way to backup a repo on an usb key is with git bundle: that generates only *one* file which represents your repo.
See "[How to backup a local Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)".

```
cd /path/to/your/local/repo/F
git bundle create <usb_drive_letter>:\F.bundle --all
```