# Incremental backups with git bundle, for all branches

Tags: git, backup

What is the easiest way to do incremental backups of a git repository with `git bundle`?

If I just wanted to backup a single branch, I could do something along these lines:

```
git bundle create foo last-backup..master
git tag -f last-backup master
```

But what if I want to backup everything (including all branches)?

---

To answer the questions in the comments:

Strictly speaking, I do not need to use the usual Git bundles, as long as the solution satisfies the following properties:

- Each incremental backup is a single file. I can store it somewhere and subsequent incremental backups do not need to modify this file.
- The size of the file is approximately equal to the total size of Git commits since the previous backup. Changes in binary files are also efficiently stored.
- A full backup + all incremental backups since then contain everything that I need to automatically reconstruct the repository, including all branches.

(As a naive example, simply constructing a tar archive with recently-changed files in the git repository fails to satisfy the second requirement if, for example, automatic garbage collection has occurred.)

And ideally I would also like to have a system that is idiot-proof:

- I can take virtually any full backup of my Git repository, plus all recent incremental backups, and I can simply "pull" everything from the backups and the repository will be up-to-date. In particular, it does not matter if there is a partial overlap between the full backup and incremental backups.

Git bundles satisfy all this very nicely if I only need to handle one branch.

Comment: Why do you need to use git bundles for backups? Is that a PHB requirement?

Comment: @user1338062: Bundles would be ideal for my workflow. If you have an alternative solution that achieves all the nice properties of Git bundles, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: You probably should expand the question a bit with what are your requirements for git repository backup.

Comment: This question (and the answers there) seem to be somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635952/how-to-use-git-bundle-for-keeping-development-in-sync

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(We discussed this problem with Jukka, this is the outcome.)

Preliminaries:

1. Have the last backup available as `backup.bundle`
2. Have a remote `backup` that points at `backup.bundle`

Making a backup:

1. `git fetch backup` – just to make sure we're up to date
2. `git bundle create newbackup.bundle ^backup/A ^backup/B A B C`

   - This means we create a bundle that excludes all the stuff that was already in the bundle
   - It's easy to generate the needed `^backup/A`-style arguments from `refs/remotes/backup/`
   - Likewise the `A`-style arguments are from `refs/heads`
3. copy `newbackup.bundle` to wherever you keep your backups
4. replace `backup.bundle` with `newbackup.bundle` so you know where to start the next incremental backup

Recovering:

1. Have a repository that is either empty or represents an old version of your repository
2. For every backup file, in sequence:

   1. `git remote rm recovery`
   2. `git remote add recovery <name-of-bundle>`
   3. `git fetch recovery` – you need to name the remote for this to work
3. Now you should have every branch available in `refs/remotes/backup`

Comment: Reading the `.git/refs/heads` and `.git/refs/remotes/backup` directories does not seem to work as intended, so I ended up invoking `git branch` and `git branch -r` and parsing the output. Other than that, this basic approach seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I think I understand what this approach is doing, I just don't understand the "It's easy to generate..." statements. How would I generate the excludes from refs/remotes/backup (and presumably the includes from refs/heads?) It is just a matter of doing an ls() on the directory and constructing the arguments from that?

Answer (score 6):

Try using --since with --all.

Create the first backup:

```
git bundle create mybundle-all --all
```

Do an incremental backup:

```
git bundle create mybundle-inc --since=10.days --all
```

The incremental should contain all commits on all branches that have happened in the past 10 days.  Make sure the --since parameter goes back far enough or you might miss a commit.  Git will also refuse to create the bundle if no commits have happened in that time-frame, so plan for that.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I wonder if I could easily use, e.g., tags instead of trying to calculate the right number of days for the `--since` flag?

Comment: You could specify a date e.g. `--since {2012-08-30}` and encode the date into last increment bundle file name.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
git clone --mirror <your_repo> my-backup.git
```

It will create a bare repo with all refs.

Then you could periodically do `git push --mirror <my-backup>`.

Comment: This is a good tip, but unfortunately it does not answer the question… I need to create bundles.

Comment: You can run the command for creating a bundle using the git hooks after each push

Comment: @jkremser: Can I write a hook that creates a bundle that contains all commits in the push, even if there are multiple branches involved? How?

Answer (score -1):

Seems **opqdonut** solution will not work, cause ^backup/A ^backup/B only points to last incremental backup. And actually need to exclude refs from all previous incremental backups.

Need to create remotes for each of previous bundles.

UPD: No, it should work, see Jukka comment below.

Comment: Example:
two branches: A, B (to simplify: no common commits between)
first 10 backups: only A modified; 11th backup: B modified
;12th backup last bundle contains only "B" refs, so new bundle will contain all "A" refs (including those which were in first 10 backups)

Comment: UPD: here is example implementation https://github.com/vsespb/git-incremental-backup

Comment: In your scenario, after the 11th backup, both backup/A and backup/B will exist, and both of them will be up-to-date. Fetching from the 11th bundle does not delete backup/A. Note that you will never *delete* the remote called "backup", you just fetch new things from the new bundles.

Comment: Yo're right. I was deleting the remote. That was the problem.