# Enabling my coworker to do git put without him being connected to the repo

Tags: git, git-remote

I am currently away from home, but have my work laptop with my. On it, I have a Git repo that I created because I am the only one who really does anything on this particular project.

I shared the folder and gave my coworker the rights to clone the git repo to his machine (as a remote branch)

He now needs my latest changes, normally he would do a git pull. This is not possible because I have no VPN right now and he cant connect via unsecured channels.

Is there a way to export the repo (and host it encrypted somewhere on the web) so that he can just download, unpack and import it? I want there to be no difference in the result than as if we were working normally. Also we have to be able to continue working on it together after I am back at work.

-edit- I should add that the repo is currently very small

Answer (score 5):

The git-way would be to use a bundle.

See "[Git's Little Bundle of Joy](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html)" (and [`git bundle` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)):

- this would generate only *one* file (easier to transfer/copy around)
- your user can *clone* or *fetch* from it (like it was a regular repo): no need to unzip.

Once an initial complete bundle has been sent, you can send [incremental bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216898/6309) for subsequent changes.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes: what I don't like with zipping the `.git` is that you bring everything, including hooks. A bundle is like a git repo, and contain only the data.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth note: I didn't downvoted your answer though ;)

Comment: I didn't assume that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply zip up your `.git` folder, encrypt it and send it via Email.

Comment: A more space efficient option for large repos is to encrypt patches in a zip file. Note, however, that certain organizations like the NSA might actually have the algorithms or hardware necessary to break the encryption on a zip file (depending on what kind of encryption you use). PGP/GPG with large keys might be a safer option, in my non-expert speculation.

Comment: and he would just replace his .git folder with it? So no git commands involved at all, just replacing everything to create an exact clone?

Comment: @buddybubble: That really depends on whether he has local changes or not. I would actually extract it to a different folder and add it as a remote.