# Backup only "local" commits / objects in git repository

Tags: git, backup

I'd like to back up (via dropbox or google drive or similar) the unpushed commits in my local repository.  Backing up the entire repository (with `git push --mirror` or similar) is redundant, since 99% of its commits exist in the central shared repo, as well as on all the other developers' machines on our team.  Also, a full clone of the repo may exceed my quota in my target backup system.

I think what I want is some sort of `git bundle` command, but I'm not sure how to pass the equivalent of `--all not in any remote refs` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216898/3150057) sets out the basic principle of using `^<remote>/<branch>` to exclude all commits reachable from the remote branch.

This script should get you going:

```shell
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18359250/3150057 for awk branch parsing.
# Get all local branch names.
LOCAL_HEADS=$(git branch | awk -F ' +' '! /\(no branch\)/ {print $2}')
# Get all remote branch names, prefixed with ^ to 'not' them.
REMOTE_HEADS=$(git branch -r | awk -F ' +' '! /\(no branch\)/ {print "^"$2}')

# -- is needed at the end to tell git we are only giving it revisions.
# List all commits reachable from local branches and tags but exclude those reachable by the remote branches.
git rev-list $REMOTE_HEADS $LOCAL_HEADS --tags --
# Pass the same args to create a bundle of all the above commits.
git bundle create my-backup-today.bundle $REMOTE_HEADS $LOCAL_HEADS --tags --
```

Comment: I'm at a different machine to the setup I made to test the above script so I can't say for sure, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/3150057) mentions the `--tags` option. However, I think that will be *all tags*, not just those pointing to commits going into the bundle.

Comment: Having read the man page for `rev-list`, `--tags` will include all tags as commits. You can limit with `--tags=<pattern>`, but there's no need since you want to add all commits bar those in `$REMOTE_HEADS`. Updated the answer to include tags.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your repository is huge, I'm not sure that I see the benefit of bypassing `git push`.

Once you've done it the first time your `push`es become incremental, and getting data back out of your private remote is super easy. Your new `private-remote/*` remote branches visually show you what's been `push`ed and what hasn't.

With `git bundle` your workflow becomes more complex, and you lose visibility of which commits are backed up.

Comment: I would schedule these backups to happen periodically in the background, so visibility is not really necessary (and may even be a negative distraction).