# Transferring changes made to multiple branches using git-bundle

Tags: git, git-bundle

I was looking for git-bundles as an option to keep my 2 repositories (being continuously worked on) in sync with each other.

Since both are two different geographical locations and setting up a VPN is also not an option I plan to use bundles..(Any other better alternative or method? )

I stumbled upon [Jefromi's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635952/how-to-use-git-bundle-for-keeping-development-in-sync/3639182#3639182) . It explains things very well.

However if I have multiple branches being worked on and I wanted to update them all, how do I do it?

(The answer uses basis for master but uses --branches that will copy the complete history of all other branches in bundle again. I want only updated/added commits of all braches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new backup while excluding what was in the previous backup:

```
git fetch ../backup.bundle
git bundle create ../newbackup.bundle ^backup/A ^backup/B A B C
```

Here you create an incremental backup with incremental history for branches `A` and `B`, plus the new branch `C`.

You can see that approach detailed in "[Incremental backups with git bundle, for all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216898/6309)"

I prefer the simpler approach of using the [date of the last backup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12212923/6309):

```
cd myRepo
git bundle create mybundle-inc --since=10.days --all
```

It is ok to backup "a bit more": duplicate commits won't be imported twice when you will use that incremental backup.

I have made a script based on `--since`: [save_bundles](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/a56de29c80a7547d9db7dc15937b521d3935473d/sbin/save_bundles#L170-L175).

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b48981987956d7cb10c5d7cddbf08d5837bc753/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> learns `--stdin` option to read its refs from the standard input.

See [commit 5bb0fd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb), [commit ce1d6d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce1d6d9f1641d87a66c3933255531ee2c15d3143), [commit 9901164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9901164d81dfc2e050860f7dd60e5590c3cfaa50) (11 Jan 2021) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8b48981](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b48981987956d7cb10c5d7cddbf08d5837bc753), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb): arguments can be read from stdin
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jiang Xin</sup>

> In order to create an incremental bundle, we need to pass many arguments to let [`git-bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> ignore some already packed commits.
> It will be more convenient to pass args via stdin.
> But the current implementation does not allow us to do this.
>
> This is because args are parsed twice when creating bundle:
>
> - The first time for parsing args is in `compute_and_write_prerequisites()` by running `git-rev-list` command to write prerequisites in bundle file, and stdin is consumed in this step if "`--stdin`" option is provided for `git-bundle`.
> - Later nothing can be read from stdin when running `setup_revisions()` in `create_bundle()`.
>
> The solution is to parse args once by removing the entire function `compute_and_write_prerequisites()` and then calling function `setup_revisions()`.
> In order to write prerequisites for bundle, will call `prepare_revision_walk()` and `traverse_commit_list()`.
> But after calling `prepare_revision_walk()`, the object array `revs.pending` is left empty, and the following steps could not work properly with the empty object array (`revs.pending`).
> Therefore, make a copy of `revs` to `revs_copy` for later use right after calling `setup_revisions()`.
>
> The copy of `revs_copy` is not a deep copy, it shares the same objects with `revs`.
> The object array of `revs` has been cleared, but objects themselves are still kept.
> Flags of objects may change after calling `prepare_revision_walk()`, we can use these changed flags without calling the [`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> command and parsing its output like the former implementation.

So [for instance](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb0fd2cab5a18bc188c8154097857f51a0e9feb#diff-35544943e284fa37f53a76d81343246df95753a2c48ab38771924a2fb3bf17f0R284-R295):

```bash
    # create bundle from stdin
    # input has a non-exist reference: "topic/deleted"
    cat >input <<-EOF &&
    ^topic/deleted
    ^$D
    ^topic/2
    EOF

    git bundle create stdin-2.bdl \
        --ignore-missing \
        --stdin \
        release <input
```

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/95de3763498a5a092a454bb548d40e918c2870c1/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> learned that `-` is a common way to say that the input comes from the standard input and/or the output goes to the standard output.

It used to work only for output and only from the root level of the working tree.

See [commit 0bbe103](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bbe10313e0b61812082d47431e8648f9df48f15), [commit 7ce4088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ce4088ab78e06fc5c4ae42fc75b65a48bf7b3ff), [commit ef3b291](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef3b291a5f19d7e3b7f4cc4524003e50d40614f7), [commit bf8b1e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf8b1e04ffa3bb6c64bb8ae50ec825b128ef957d) (04 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit a8bfa99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8bfa99d443d3c461217db4924f8eca24caa055a) (04 Mar 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 95de376](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95de3763498a5a092a454bb548d40e918c2870c1), 19 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf8b1e04ffa3bb6c64bb8ae50ec825b128ef957d): let "`-`" mean stdin for reading operations
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> For writing, "`bundle create -`" indicates that the bundle should be written to stdout.
> But there's no matching handling of "`-`" for reading operations.
> This is inconsistent, and a little inflexible (though one can always use "`/dev/stdin`" on systems that support it).
>
> However, it's easy to change.
> Once upon a time, the bundle-reading code required a seekable descriptor, but that was fixed long ago in [e9ee84c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9ee84cf28b6c7e5079ab3c020c86a44900a3f46) ("`bundle`: allowing to read from an unseekable fd", 2011-10-13, Git v1.7.8-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b76c561a74cd366786b7b762795fba1551b42149)).
> So we just need to handle "`-`" explicitly when opening the file.
>
> We *could* do this by handling "`-`" in `read_bundle_header()`, which the reading functions all call already.
> But that is probably a bad idea.
> It's also used by low-level code like the transport functions, and we may want to be more careful there.
> We do not know that stdin is even available to us, and certainly we would not want to get confused by a configured URL that happens to point to "`-`".
>
> So instead, let's add a helper to [`builtin/bundle.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bf8b1e04ffa3bb6c64bb8ae50ec825b128ef957d/builtin/bundle.c).
> Since both the bundle code and some of the callers refer to the bundle by name for error messages, let's use the string "`<stdin>`" to make the output a bit nicer to read.

This applies to `git bundle`:

- `create`
- `verify <file>`
- `list-heads <file>`
- `unbundle <file>`

Comment: As always you are the saviour.