# Disconnecting: Protocol error: expected packet type 31, got 94

Tags: git, ssh

when ever we try to clone over ssh the  audio repo which is of  65+GB in size , we are getting below Error . Any suggestion  please ?

we are able to clone using file:// protocol & repo heath is fine ...

> git clone ssh://server-gerrit/project_Q2/audio
>   Cloning into 'audio'...
>   X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
>   remote: Counting objects: 23944, done
>   remote: Finding sources: 100% (23944/23944)
>   Disconnecting: Protocol error: expected packet type 31, got 94
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-5472) proposes the following workaround, using a shallow clone:

> Workaround Git 1.8+:

```
#find the highest N that will work
git clone --depth N  ssh://git@stashhost:7999/stash/stash.git
git fetch --unshallow
```

---

Since it doesn't work, I mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790088/disconnecting-protocol-error-expected-packet-type-31-got-94/29790354?noredirect=1#comment47756180_29790354) the [bundle technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309), which allows for [incremental bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989104/transferring-changes-made-to-multiple-branches-using-git-bundle/24989477#24989477).

The OP adds:

> We split the repo and managed it that way.

Comment: @Jayanth even with depth 1?

Comment: @Jayanth then can you try to bundle the repo and transfer it hat way? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309 (you can make lultiple incremental bundles: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24989477/6309)

Comment: @Jayanth Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.