# Clone repo with only several branches available

Tags: git, git-branch

The case is following. I should give a copy of a repo to someone as an archive.
There are lots of branches but I want there to be only several.
As far as I know all the branches are copied on a local machine by default even though only `master` is visible until you switch to another one by `git branch`.

Say we have: `branch1`, `branch2` and `branch3`.
I want someone only to be able to access `branch1` and `branch2` as a result.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you give a copy of a repository, use [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle): that will create one file (easy to transfer), without any potentially sensitive information from your local Git repository config.
And the "someone" can then `git clone` from that file!

Second, when using [`git bundle create`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#Documentation/git-bundle.txt-createoptionsltfilegtltgit-rev-list-argsgt), you can list the branches you want to be included, as I [illustrate here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989477/6309).