# Git Source Control between two networks

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

Currently we develop on network 1 using TFS as source control.

I burn a CD with all the code and bring it to network 2. Do some testing, make changes if needed. Changes are hand written on paper, then I go back to network 1 and manually enter in the changes.

I would like a better solution. We are updating to Visual Studio 2013 and I noticed it includes Git. What would be the best way for me to make a copy of the code on network 1 and load the project back up on network 2?

Restrictions:
Transfer from network 1 to network 2 can only be done with a CD.
Transfer from network 2 to network 1 can only be done manually with paper and pen.

I would like to be able to track changes made on network 2 and easily import a new version of network 1 code onto network 2.

Could this be done by cloning the repository on network 1, then burning the files to a disk and loading the files on network 2? Can I point Visual Studio Git to a local repository file structure and "import" the project?

Comment: The source control system you use seems to be irrelevant given the transfer constraints (pen and paper???) you list.

Comment: I usually applaud the work done as moderator by Andrew Barber, but I have no idea why this perfectly legitimate question was closed. For what it's worth, the answer is git bundle: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this be done by cloning the repository on network 1, then burning the files to a disk and loading the files on network 2?

In essence, yes. With Git, an easy way to achieve that is to use [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle), which I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309).

Once created, a bundle is *one* single file, very easy to backup/copy around (less error-prone than copying a large number of files)

It acts as a git repo, which means you can clone it or fetch from it.

You can see a similar scenario in "[How to use `git bundle` for keeping development in sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639182/6309)".