# FDT - Accessing Same Project from Different Computers with Google Drive - Error "Project description file is missing"

Tags: google-drive-api, fdt

I am using the latest subscription version of FDT 64 bit (with a subscription, not the free version). I have my FDT workspace and project files saved in my Google Drive. I am trying to work on the same FDT project from two computers: A Windows 7 desktop, and a new MacBook Pro.

Disclaimer: I am new to FDT, since just getting the MacBook I am trying out moving from FlashDevelop to FDT so that I can have a native IDE on both my desktop and laptop.

I created the project and started working on it while going through FDT tutorials on the Windows 7 desktop. Compiling, debugging, everything was working great. I am now trying to open the project and work on it from the MacBook. Upon launching FDT and choosing the workspace in Google Drive (which has finished syncing) I can see the project in the FDT Explorer, but if I try to open it by double-clicking on it I am presented with the error:

"'Open Project' has encountered a problem. The project description file (.project) for 'My Project' is missing. This file contains important information about the project. The project will not function properly until this file is restored."

However, showing hidden files and browsing with Finder shows that the .project file is indeed there, as well as every other file in the project's folder. I compared the contents of the files on the PC and Mac, and they appear to be the same.

Other notes: Both the desktop and MacBook have the 64-bit version of FDT installed.

My desired outcome is to easily move from my Windows desktop to my MacBook and continue working on the same project. Perhaps I'm doing it all wrong with trying to use Google Drive and setting the workspaces to be the same. Please critique and tell me how I should be doing it :)

Comment: Using file sync services & software can be dicey. My FDT & Eclipse projects would often get corrupted when using Dropbox.  It's best to avoid these services because they can mess things up as they intermittently sync your files, and it's auto merge is not concerned with making sure the sync is 100% correct. You're better off using a typical VCS. In these cases PC<->OSX projects have not issues.

Comment: I'd also advise a version control system instead of a shared network drive, be it Dropbox or Google Drive. You get the appropriate workflow for your project, the benefits are countless. You can get a free Git account at https://bitbucket.org for up to 5 developers.

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research based off of the comments on my question, I decided to use a version control system instead of a network drive. A shared network drive is just not the right workflow for something like this, and corrupted files will always be an issue. I am now using BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/

See here for more related information:
[DropBox as Version Control and Offsite Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891361/dropbox-as-version-control-and-offsite-backup/5892635#5892635)

Update: For anyone getting started with Bit Bucket, this is what I used to get started:

This tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pp2S2lHjzZI (it's for Git Hub but works fine with Bit Bucket)

I am using TortoiseGit on windows, and Tower for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you should confirm on your Mac to resolve the problem (in Terminal):

1. Check if the file is there `ls ~/Google\ Drive/[your_project]/.project`
2. Change file rights for the file `sudo chmod 0777 ~/Google\ Drive/[your_project]/.project`