# Using svn/git with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I like to use either git or svn for my Xcode projects, but need to be able to access them from outside e.g. from another machine somewhere.

So I need a repository somewhere, but I don't want to use any third party service like github.

What do I need to run any of the two on an external rented server (e.g. ruling out one of my machines using dyndns)?
Would some web-space somewhere be sufficient?
If not, what do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is a computer you can ssh into if you don't need to share the repo with anyone else. I use a VPS at Dreamhost for this.

If you really want a Git server, I would recommend using Gitosis which is open source git server software. You can checkout the github repo [here](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis). Also, gere are a whole bunch of tutorials to get you started:

> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Gitosis
>
> http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way
>
> http://www.markrichman.com/2008/06/16/installing-git-and-gitosis-on-ubuntu/
>
> http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-gitosis-on-ubuntu

Comment: Not Gitosis. Gitosis is outdated and abandoned (though word about that seems to be spreading slowly or not at all). Use Gitolite instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) as supposed in this question: [Git with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox)

A detailed guide is provided in this answer: [Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively/1961515#1961515)

The main advantage of dropbox is, that you **don't** need a box you can ssh into, instead you use dropbox as repo storage... And – not to forget – if you can deal with the basic account (up to 2 GB storage), it's **free**. Even the Pro package for 100 GB is quite affordable.