# git clone never completes

Tags: git

I am trying to use git clone on Mac OS Snow Leopard. All I do is "git clone https://***/project.git" from documents/projects directory. For some reason operation never completes and stops at random points somewhere at the "Receiving Files:" stage(different % of copied files each time). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What remote are you using? I have had problems clning using a VPS with not enough memory before.

Comment: We can't tell whether you're doing something wrong if you don't tell us what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I have usually seen this symptom on repos with a "resource locked" issue, because of some processes keeping an handle on one of the git files.

Last time was for a git repo directly part of a Dropbox shared directory. (Which is why I always recommend to [share in a Dropbox directory only the bundle, not the all git repo structure itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox/3633346#3633346))

Comment: But if something is locked then I guess it should always stuck at certain point. But for me it can stop one time at 7% another time at 67%. Completely random.

Comment: @Aleksey that's my point: the DropBox sync was locking a different resource every time when synchronizing different part of the many files of a Git repo structure. Hence the randomness. Depending on the nature of the process locking resources, that randomness can apply too here.