# VCS for a development, testing, production environment

Tags: php, git, svn, cvs, development-environment

I'm looking at several VC systems and wondering what suits my needs better.

Right now, I have the following:

- My local machine (Win7) where I code with php with the PhpStorm.
- A Debian Linux machine set up in my internal network.
- A Debian Linux dedicated web server.

Ideally, I wan't to code in this machine, push any chances I make locally to my internal webserver (where I see the changes and test them out) and if all is good, push them to the web server.

**Which VC system do you suggest: Git, SVN or CVS?**

Comment: Develop on Windows deploy to Linux, work out the differences, application is solid, my 2cents

Comment: I understood the question was about which VC system to use. Added the question.

Comment: I obviously couldn't figure out the question :)

Comment: My conclusion was due to the first sentence and the tags :)

Comment: Might aswell change the question title to match the question. This question is quite localized in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. That's exactly what I meant. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- CVS is a little outdated and bears quite some problems compared to SVN
- SVN is okay but you will need to setup your own server which means too much effort for a single developer environment
- Git is maybe a little bit unusual when you are comming from a traditional VC as it's a distributed version control system. But once you get used to it you understand the strengths no matter if you are working alone or in a big, distributed team. You don't need to setup any server and it's even possible to share your repository with others via [DropBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox).

So I'd suggest Git. Find the documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/documentation).

Answer (score 2):

Too late, but I'll suggest to use (or at least try) [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

- It's [supported](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/supported-version-control-systems.html) by PHPStorm
- It's more understandable as first SCM, than Git (and as not-first also)
- It's not "poor cousin" in Windows world ([TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), if needed outside PHPStorm)
- With MQ it provide more easier way for Configuration Management (because configurations of DEV and LIVE systems *may differ*)
- Sharing (sporadical) repo in Mercurial (for pull-mode data-delivery) is a question of single internal Mercurial command `hg serve`, for Git situation is **a lot** worse

Answer (score 0):

I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) to code webpages. It has an realy good build in ftp browser, so you can vieuw and edit the required file, and when you hit ctrl+s (save the file) the file on the ftp server will be updated.

So if you have an FTP server on that internal server, i recommend you to use aptana then. And use any ftp software for the final push...

Comment: Aptana also supports GIT

Comment: You're right, forgot about that because i didn't use it. But your right

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend any of them that work on windows, which I'm assuming is where you are happiest to develop on.

I know GIT (GitBash) does because I use it myself, pretty sure SVN does, and theres a version of CVS that does (Tortoise CVS?)

I haven't used phpStorm yet (keep meaning to), but as the other answer mentioned Aptana I'll point out that Aptana has built in support for GIT

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems =)

can recommend 
develop on native envirement 
make few virtual hosts on deban web server  like dev.host_name  test.host_name

make shared folder on debian server (using samba), make network disk on your win 7 and connect  to share folder   and work with  folders dev and test like on own computer