# Use Hudson to build a specific git commit

Tags: git, hudson

I have a hudson build server. The source code is managed by a git repository. For each build the latest version is checked out and compiled. Now i'd like to tell hudson to use not the latest version, but an older version of the code (specified by me).

In hudson i have two parameters which can be set. First "name of repository", with default value "origin" and second `refspec` with value `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. I tried a bit around something like `origin/[commitid]` or `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/[commitid]`. But nothing worked as expected.

I think i had to use a parameterized job, so that i can give the commit as parameter to the job.

How can i tell hudson to use a specific commit instead of the latest one?

Answer (score 57):

I just want to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22097982/1579623) answer more clear.
How to make your job to checkout a specific commit, step by step:

1. Add string parameter to your job with name, let it be `COMMIT` in my example.
2. Choose Git as SCM (provided by [Jenkins Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)).
3. In Git SCM properties set your repo properties.
4. In Git SCM, in the paragraph **Branches to build** type `${COMMIT}` which is the reference to the job parameter and will be resolved during the build.

That's it, launch the build and in the log you will see something like this:

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh://your-repo.git
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://your-repo.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://your-repo.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Checking out Revision af63e2102b65953316e512c0bb659578bb143a33 (detached)
```

Note, that there are other ways to set the environment variable before the SCM checkout, i.e. using `Prepare environment for the run` step from the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) (you could even use Groovy for this).

Also, if you don't see the options I'm talking about or they don't work, ensure you have a new version of a Git plugin In my case it is 2.2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. Worked like a charm!

Comment: How do you "launch the build"?  When I press "Build Now", only one branch is built (master).

Comment: Check my answer again, I suggested introducing a parameter. When job is parameterized, the user sees BuildWithParameters form when hit "Build" link instead of immediate build start.

Comment: For the lazy, this also works without using build parameters, you can simply paste the commit identifier into "Branches to build".

Comment: Upvoted as I found that some of my colleagues prefer to modify the job config directly, for them this is more straightforward and easier to understand.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that simply pasting the commit hash into the "Branches to build" field is not compatible with "Advanced clone behaviours > Shallow clone".

Comment: **Remove** the "Lightweight checkout" checkbox selection. Then it worked for me. Otherwise not!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the branch parameter of the [jenkins-git-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to define a specific commit id.

Jenkins will then only checkout that commit and not the head of a branch.

Comment: If you click the little question mark (?) next to the field it says: `...A specific revision can be checked out by specifying the SHA1 hash of that revision in this field.`  This feels to me like the "right way to do it".

Comment: Which question mark? I cannot find any question mark anywhere. What format should I follow to specify the revision? What if I'm using a pipeline? The documentation is practically useless.

Answer (score 7):

Like the documentation says:

[image: git plugin branch configure]

Input your commit id to the "Branches to build" setting.

Comment: I would love to find that documentation. I cannot find anything like that screenshot on the official site.

Comment: @cauchy, this documentation is not on the site, it's in your Jenkins instance, in the job configuration, under Source Code Management->Branches to Build->?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. In order to work, the option "Lightweight checkout" must be **disabled**.

Answer (score 4):

In "Pre Steps" try to add "Execute shell" and add:

```
   git pull
   git checkout <commit version>
```

Comment: Note: This means the GIT_COMMIT environment variable no longer matches the actual commit that is checked out.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround would be to:

- set the Git plugin to build a special "`build_br`" branch.
- **reset the branch `build_br` to the expected commit**
- push that branch `build_br` to remote repo monitor by Jenkins or Hudson (that would be a `push --force`, as illustrated in "[`git reset --hard` and a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1377845/6309)")

That way, building that branch `build_br` would mean building a specific commit, and the GIT_COMMIT will be correctly set.
No development should take place on that special branch, since it is reset regularly to any commit you need to be build.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your Hudson job to build a specific branch. Then you can push whatever changes you want Hudson to build onto that branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Hudson, but Jenkins' Git Plugin has an "Advanced..." button at the right just above the "Repository browser" field. Clicking there reveals a lot of additional options, one of them being "Checkout/merge to local branch (optional)". Its help text says "If given, checkout the revision to build as HEAD on this branch. Please note that this has not been tested with submodules", so that seems to be what you have in mind.