# Jenkins run a build against a specified git commit version

Tags: git, jenkins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Hudson to build a specific git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207450/use-hudson-to-build-a-specific-git-commit)

I want to start a build via the API, using parametized builds. I want to pass the commit code into a parameter through this, which works fine.

I then want to use the commit code to run a build on that commit version with git.

Is there a way to make jenkins run a build against a specific commit?

thanks in advance!