# Undo last commit/merge

Tags: git, version-control, commit, revert

I have messed up my git repo a little. I worked on a feature in a separate branch. After finishing the work, I switched to the master to merge it into, but my partner pushed a few files which came into conflict with mine. After the merge, the conflict and pushing the new changes, I saw that I committed the older changes of my partner too.

Now I want to redo this commit/merge. I tried 
`git reset --soft HEAD^` but when I wanted to push, I got this error message `Merge the remote changes before pushing again`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository

Answer (score 58):

Your feature branch will still point to your work. You will not lose those changes.

As plaes said, you can reset master back one with

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If you want to grab some specific files from your branch without merging, you can check them out:

```
git checkout yourbranch -- file1 file2 etc
```

If you want some files from master from before the merge you can also check these out:

```
git checkout master^ -- file3 file4 etc
```

This is not ideal but it is what is needed sometimes. A merge /may/ mean that you reject some changes from either side in a merge. The best way to attain a proper merge is to:

```
git merge --no-commit yourbranch
```

from master, then run the git checkout commands from above and finally commit:

```
git add . -A
git commit
```

When you push this branch now, you will need to add the `force` option

```
git push --force
```

or

```
git push -f
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply adymitruk, i tried the git `reset --hard HEAD^` and after that git push origin +master but i get still an error with the message `! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: if you are going to lose a commit on the remote because of a push, you need to tell git that it's ok with the `--force` or `-f` option. Updating answer.

Answer (score 21):

Hehe, you almost figured it out:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Comment: Hey plaes thanks for the answer, but i want to keep the files i have pushed wrongly. Is there a solution for it?

Comment: `git reset --soft` may help you.

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you want to undo changes that you already have pushed to the central repository. If you hadn't pushed them in the first place, a git reset --hard/--soft/--mixed HEAD^ would have done the trick.

So when you have reseted your HEAD git complains when you try to push to the origin and update the remote ref which is not an ancestor to your HEAD. Use --force:

```
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Use git reset --hard origin/master instead, this will do hard reset as well as delete the merge as well. Take from link [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet)

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify it for the users that don't understand git very well, like me :D

If you want to unmerge the commit and remove it from the remote git as well. Follow:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

or

```
git reset --merge hash-of-commit-before-merge i.e. c4ab5de
```

Now you have successfully reset on your local, it's time to update/sync this on remote

```
git push --force // this will remove the merge or afterwards commits
```