# Git clear remote repository

Tags: git

If I push a bad initial commit (or more than one) to a remote repository and want to just clear it / destroy it - can I do it by a command?

It's important to totally remove it from server so it doesn't use disk space.

E.G. Today I pushed a whole Visual Studio project with included dlls, sdfs and so on. Firstly this files are quite big, secondly some of them are modified by VS of other developers and than can't be merged. This made me google a little bit and I found out these files should be ignored. But the first commit already clutters my repository. I want to remove this and free the disk space.

It's possible to remove git repo and add it again via host's website (assembla), but this doesn't sound like solution to me.. Is there a more professional way?

---

UPDATE:

I tried suggestions from the answer below but it didn't work:
'git push -f' 'git push --force' 'git push origin -f' 'git push origin --force'
resulted in:

```
$ git push --force
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 6.85 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull fir
)
To git@git.assembla.com:xxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.assembla.com:xxxxx.git'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force push the "correct" repo with `git push -f`.  Depending on the host, the loose objects will be cleaned up when `git gc` is ran.  *update: According to [this](http://feedback.assembla.com/forums/5433-feature-requests/suggestions/1016769-allow-git-gc) you can't force the `git gc` in assembla.*

If you want them cleaned up immediately and assembla doesn't allow you to force a `git gc`, the other option is to delete the repo and push a new one.

In addition, as Ryan stated in the comments, be sure to let everyone know that may have cloned the repo, that you re-wrote history.

Comment: +1, but 1) be sure garbage collection is running regularly, as orphaned objects won't be cleaned up until they become eligible, and 2) make sure everyone knows you're rewriting history.

Comment: If you can, force a deletion of the remote master branch `git push origin :master`.  Some remote repository configurations won't allow for this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'delete the repo'? Is there a special command for that, or you just mean to do this via assembla webpage?

Comment: @gisek Yes, delete it through assembla's interface.

Comment: Hmm, looks like 'git push -f' doesn't work. Details added to the question.

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository/1377930#1377930) issue.  I'd check with assembla.