# Git total reset. Remove all files. Remove history

Tags: git, ssh, openshift

I have an existing repository (at `ssh://xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com/~/git/dev.git/`) which isn't cloned to my computer. It's too big and messy and I don't want to download it, I don't need it anymore. I want to start fresh and totally replace its content. How do I do that?

I have used SmartGit before to commit. I can also connect to my repository through `ssh xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com` in Git Bash. That's pretty much all I know about git. All I want is to reset a repository in such a way that when I clone it to my computer all I get is an empty directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git clear remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451534/git-clear-remote-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a local git repo, add an initial commit, add your remote and force push:

```
$ mkdir newfolder && cd newfolder
$ git init
$ touch README.md
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git remote add openshift ssh://xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com/~/git/dev.git/
$ git push openshift master -f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing a step by step instruction. Worked like a charm.

Comment: If I interpret everything correctly, this changes just the master branch without affecting other branches.

Answer (score 5):

If you have actually access to the remote git server, you can with ssh, do a soft delete:

```
ssh xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com
cd ~/git/
mv dev.git dev.old.git
git init --bare dev.git
```

Then you can clone again that repo, and start from scratch.

```
git clone ssh://xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com/~/git/dev.git
cd dev
# the folder is empty
```

---

Since the folder `~/git` is owned by `root`, you can simply create a new `dev` bare repo elsewhere:

```
ssh xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com
cd ~
mkdir newgit
cd newgit
git init --bare dev.git
```

Then

```
git clone ssh://xxx@yyy.rhcloud.com/~/newgit/dev.git
cd dev
# the folder is empty
```

Comment: mv command errors `mv: cannot move `dev.git' to `dev.git.old': Permission denied`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What user/group owns that folder? Try ls -alrth

Comment: seems like I (xxx) am the owner  `drwxr-xr-x.  8 xxx xxx 4.0K Jul 10 06:50 dev.git` but root owns the ~/git folder `drwxr-xr-x.  3 root                     root                       20 Dec 25  2015 .`

Comment: OK, but who owns the parent folder?

Comment: Yes, you need to find another folder owned by you, in which you can do the git init bare, since the MV won't work.

Comment: using a different folder isn't an option because openshift has to run an application I commit from a certain folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change/remove the remote, you can clone the repository with `--deph` option set to 1 in order to clone only the last commit:

```
git clone --depth=1 bigmessyrepo
```

It does not change the remote, but your local one will be more lightweight.