# Push older git repo to origin (remote)

Tags: git

I pushed a change to a remote test git repo, then reset my local git repo to HEAD^, and now am trying to push my local repo to origin, but I get a "non fast forward" merger warning.  If I do a `git pull`, my local repo gets nuked by the origin.

How can I either merge in the origin repo and tell it to throw away the merges from the origin or tell origin to accept my push, even though it is not a fast forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub help page](http://help.github.com/remotes/) does summarize it nicely:

> This error can be a bit overwhelming at first, do not fear.
>   Simply put, **git cannot make the change on the remote without losing commits, so it refuses the push**.
>   Usually this is caused by another user pushing to the same branch.
>   You can remedy this by fetching and merging the remote branch, or using pull to perform both at once.
>
> In other cases this error is a result of destructive changes made locally by using commands like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`.

(In your case, a `git reset --hard`)

> While you can override the remote by adding `--force` to the `push` command, you should only do so if you are absolutely certain this is what you want to do.
>   **Force-pushes can cause issues for other users that have fetched the remote branch, and is considered bad practice**.
>   When in doubt, don’t force-push.

The question "[Git reset --hard and a remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377845/git-reset-hard-and-a-remote-repository)" adds that you need to be aware of the potential remote config **`receive.denyNonFastForwards`**, which can deny your "`git push --force`".
In which case, some kind of revert needs to take place: alternatives are discussed at "[GIT revert to previous commit… how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how)".