# git rollback changes to changeset many changes ago(almost 1 week ago), not just a few commits

Tags: git, changeset

I need to roll back our master branch to a changeset almost 1 week ago and many changesets ago.

i have tried 
`git reset --hard <changeset>`  I get an error trying to push to origin , it won't allow me to use --force

My ultimate to goal is to straighten up both my local and remote repos, not just local.

Comment: remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/test (you should pull first)
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Comment: might be that your remote repository is configured to receive.denyNonFastForwards, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1377930/450383

Answer (score 0):

Your repository that you are trying to push to is not bare. Meaning, it has a working directory. Most likely, the master branch is checked out and may have changes in it. Git will not allow you to change the remote this way. You need to pull the changes from the remote to your machine or make a bare repo and use that instead. You would rarely push to a non-bare repository.