# Changing commit message on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to change the commit message on one of my commits?
This happen to be a really old commit and doing a git rebase is not helping me.
Is there a way to make changes to my commit message given that I know the commit Id.

I have checked the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381044/how-do-i-change-a-git-commit-message-in-bitbucket)

Comment: Why is rebase not helping you? You can't change the history without a rebase.

Comment: It's not possible if you don't want to rewrite the history.

Comment: Wrt to the link i shared rebase will ask me to check each and every commit. This commit is way down and I tried searching for it but could not get it in the list. If there is no other way out of this I will perhaps relook at the editor more closely for my changes.

Comment: You know the commit id? So you should be able to rebase without searching for anything.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: **I am trying the git rebase -i <commitId> ** , I could not get my comment

Comment: `git rebase -i <commit-id>~1` where `<commit-id>` is the ID of the commit you want to change.