# Edit pushed commit message in EGit

Tags: git, push, commit, egit

I want to edit the commit message of a pushed commit.

I tried it using the "revert Commit" button, but got this error:

> An internal error occurred
>   Cannot revert commit '9b424b08c83baffd18c2d5dffbe5bdb902c0cf63' because it has 0 parents, only commits with exactly one parent are supported

Note: It's the Initial Commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git commit --amend`. It'll allow you to change commit message of your last commit. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8981216/724972).

Comment: But I don't want to edit my last commit. I want to edit the first one.

Comment: You can use interactive rebase for in that case. http://schacon.github.io/history.html