# remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project

Tags: gitlab, git-push

I am trying to push to master branch of a repo and I am failing to do so, since it is protected.
I tried to look into the project settings and do not see any option for protected branches. The only option I could see is members.

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
To git@gitlab.ins.risk.regn.net:cmd/release.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.ins.risk.regn.net:cmd/release.git'
```

My repo has only one branch, with no contents in it so far.
I do see protected branches options of my other Repos but not for this specific one.
It is a new repo with no contents and with only default branch.
I have the `master` permission.
Unfortunately I am not able to upload the image here somehow.

Please suggest how to push code to master branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix: you are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/how-to-fix-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-this-proje)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> with no contents in it so far

That means there is no `master` branch to protect yet, because the empty repo does not has one.

To ["Enable/disable branch protection"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html), you need to be Master or Owner of the GitLab project (which you are).

Make sure:

- your [first push is a `git push -u origin master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309);
- the remote `origin` does reference the right repo (`git remote -v`);
- your local ssh key is the right one (`ssh -T git@gitlab.ins.risk.regn.net`);
- you are a member of the `cmd` group.

Answer (score 59):

12/17/2018

#### 1. `git push`: "error: failed to push some refs to"

[image: git push: error: failed to push some refs to]

#### `git push -f`: "remote rejected"

[image: git push -f: remote rejected]

#### 2. the branch is in a protected state and cannot be forced to operate.

`Gitlab - Repository - Branches`

[image: Gitlab - Repository - Branches]

#### 3. temporarily remove branch protection.

`Gitlab - Settings - Repository - Protected Branches - Unprotect`

[image: Gitlab - Settings - Repository - Protected Branches - Unprotect]

#### 4. try pushing again

`git push -f`

[image: git push -f]

#### 5. may add protection

Comment: @Coderman This is the permission management of the git repository and must be set this way.

Comment: Current version of GitLab has a slider to allow force pushed to currently protected branches.

Comment: `git push -f` is a dangerous operation, do not perform it on the public branch, only on your own temporary branch.

  Under normal circumstances, there are prompts on git bash, follow the prompts, such as performing the `pull` operation before `push` on multiple collaborative branches. Instead of force pushing, unless your team really needs to force the operation (note that it is your team, not you).

Answer (score 10):

In GitLab some branches can be protected. By default only 'master' user can commit to protected branches and master branch is protected by default.

You can turn on and off protection on selected branches in Project Settings (Go to project: "Settings" -> "Repository" -> "Expand" on "Protected branches" ).

On the same settings page you can also allow developers to push into the protected branches. With this setting on, protection will be limited to rejecting operations requiring git push --force

Answer (score 6):

It means that you may have a `master` branch, but it is protected in project settings. See:

[how to fix: you are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/how-to-fix-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-this-proje) or https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/207.

In order to access project settings and unprotect the branch, you need to have sufficient rights.

Answer (score 4):

Project: "Settings" -> "Protected branches" (if you are at least 'Master' of given project).

[image]

Then click on "Unprotect" or "Developers can push"

Answer (score 2):

Settings>Repo>Expand.. worked for me
Few branches could be secured. Keep in mind the master branch is default protected. As a matter of course the master will be able to commit to protected branches.

Check out: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/51741

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - a CI/CD pipeline/job for a project was complaining that it can't pull the code from a protected branch of a private repository on a self-hosted GitLab instance.

In my case I was able to manipulate the repositories and pull code directly with git because I had full administrative privileges in GitLab. In the end it turns out that GitLab Runner was not allowed to clone the repository because my user was not a direct member of the project group.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little old, but for me, remote was set with a prefixed user that a devops made to deploy, so I had to change remote url to don't use the username it was set, or you can change to yours.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to push to a different branch and then create a merge request from that different branch into main using the GitLab UI.

```
git push -fu origin differentbranch
```

Our reason for doing this is that locking down branches like main is a good policy.  We do not want to weaken that good policy by allowing manual overrides to it.

The merge request process in the GitLab UI only took a few seconds, so that our approach might even be faster than the other approaches offered by other answers to this old OP.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the master branch opens the protection. You need to select the developer to push in the protection branch settings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.