# GitLab Merge-Request on protected branch via CLI

Tags: git, gitlab, command-line-interface, git-merge, pull-request

Is it possible to merge a feature-branch into a protected branch via CLI?
The settings of the protected branch allow to merge for devs, but not push.

If you create a merge request there is an instructions for using the cli, but it doesn't work with the protected branch setting:

[image: CLI instructions]

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The CLI instructions are generic and don't take into account protected branch. So, the simple answer, no, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of GitLab 8.11, you can define who is allowed to push to protected branches. See [documentation about protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) to see how to specify protected branch push settings.

Apart from that, there is no way to push to a protected branch. That's why a branch is protected in the first place: to keep people from changing its contents without review (i.e. in another way than by merge requests).

EDIT:
Also see [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267118/7598462) about how to configure protected branches.