# Managing GitLab Protected Branches by CLI?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to deprotecting branches in my GitLab Group.
There are several projects(50+) in this group.
So when I try to handle permission that protects branches, I have to enter in every GitLab projects...

like below:

[Fix Gilab error: "you are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/fix-gilab-error-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-this/32267118#32267118)

I want to managing branch protect policy by command-line-tool. Is there any good solution?

Comment: I installed GitLab using docker-compose and it runs on the docker.

The GitLab container uses host mounted volumes to store persistent data:

`/srv/gitlab/data`
`/srv/gitlab/logs`
`/srv/gitlab/config`

I've look around these directories but nothing found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have to use REST API.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html