# How to change the message of a pushed commit

Tags: git

I have a git history like this:

```
date|commit hash|message
2015 10:00|12345|first commit
2015 10:05|12346|second commit
2015 10:10|12347|third commit
2015 10:15|12347|fourth commit
```

All of these commits are pushed. What's is the best way to change message of the commit with hash "12346" from "second commit" to "second commit changed"?

I am looking for simplest solution without rebasing or creating a new branch; just changing the commit message. I think that this wouldn't impact others even if someone fetch this because the commit will still have the same content and hash (only message will be different).

EDIT:

My question is not like: [Changing git commit message after push (given that no one pulled from remote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote)
because there is solution for last commit and I am looking for commit that is deper history.

Comment: there is answer for last commit, I am not looking for last commit. I am looking to edit commit from deeper history.

Comment: You can edit the message of an old commit with `git rebase -i ...`, but you'll be rewriting history. There's no way around this.

Comment: @fico7489 you're looking for a solution to a more general problem than the one in the linked to in the earlier comment, but the answer is the same: you cannot do it without rewriting history, as changing the message changes the hash.

Comment: Thank you Joost, your answer is solution to my problem, I haven't know that message is part of hash creating.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. A commit is the culmination of many things, including its message.

Changing the message would change the hash, which means it's a new commit. This would change history.

Comment: maybe some workaround ?

Comment: You can maybe use `git notes`, and then view the notes when you log it. But changing the message itself is not possible unless you want to rewrite history, which is almost never a good idea.

Comment: For more info on `git notes`, read this: http://git-scm.com/2010/08/25/notes.html