# How to change previous commit ID number with new Commit Id

Tags: git, apache

By mistake I have Commited my code with wrong Commit Id number by follwing these steps:

```
git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash apply
git add .
git commit -m "commitId: msg"
git push
git fetch
```

But now I want to change my id.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing git commit message after push (given that no one pulled from remote)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote)

Answer (score 0):

With `git amend` you can change commit message. Amend merges current change to the previous commit and will also change the commit hash and message.

```
$ git commit --amend --allow-empty -m "commitId: msg"   # Commit empty change
$ git push -f origin HEAD                               # Force (-f) push as history is changed
```