# Change commit message in intellij after push

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I pushed my git commit and realised the commit message is incorrect. How can I change the commit message from Intellij? I am the only one using the remote feature branch with this commit. What are the drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote. There's really no reason to not just do it in a command console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Edit commit message` action in Git Log in IDE as mentioned here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-project-history.html#reword-commit

Then you can do a force push as mentioned here `Ctrl/CMD+Shift+K` or Git | Push and then click on an arrow next to `Push` button and click `Force push`
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruslan. When I did Force Push I got a message: You are going to force push to <branch>. It may overwrite commits at the remote. Are you sure you want to proceed? The result was exactly what I needed. The procedure you described changed the commit message in the local branch and at the remote branch. Since nobody pulled this branch (only I am working on this feature), I believe Force Push was safe.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's suppose you did your first commit already and you want to change**. Simply open the terminal inside Intellij.

First check your commit by typing:

```
git log --oneline
```

after, if you decide to change your commit, you simply type:

```
git commit --amend -m "new commit that overrides first commit"
```

you can again check your commit by typing `git log --oneline` and if you are okay with everything, you can push it to the remote repo.