# Reword a commit using its SHA1 that has been pushed

Tags: git, github

How can I reword a commit message that has been pushed using its SHA1 hash?

Assuming that I'm on branch `feature/abc` and it hasn't been merged into `main` yet.

But the commit has been pushed to the remote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+message

Comment: I want to reword a commit using its `SHA1`, and I have explicitly mentioned that in the title. The similar question that is attached is not explaining how to do it using `SHA1`.

Comment: This answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987851/7976758 Except `git rebase -i HEAD~n` you can do `git rebase -i SHA1~`, that's the only difference. Then `git push --force` (also in the answers there).