# How to change the pushed commit message in git

Tags: git

I have pushed 10 commits using git,how to change the commit message now?

can I change the message in Github web page?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to edit your latest commit

```
git commit --amend
```

If you want to edit multiple commits use the following

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

here n is the number of commit messages, in your case it would be 10

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can t change the git message on the **remote** branch directly, Do all your changes on your **local** branch then force push updated local branch again. Check this [Changing git commit message after push (given that no one pulled from remote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote)