# Is there a way to edit the descriptions of pushed commits on GitHub?

Tags: python, github, terminal, pycharm, edit

I'm using PyCharm, so the commit text inside of it saves from the last time you pushed a commit. I forgot to change the description of my new commit and accidentally pushed it without realizing that it was wrong. While not life-changing, this is certainly inconvenient and I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this through GitHub. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, it's worthwhile to note that I have already moved on in my project, so the last commit is not the one with the mistake in it.

I tried looking around for any buttons in both PyCharm and GitHub, but could not find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing git commit message after push (given that no one pulled from remote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981194/changing-git-commit-message-after-push-given-that-no-one-pulled-from-remote)

Comment: You cannot change history. Commit description is part of the commit, and so the next commits will base on previous commit AND description -- Note: you can create a new branch and replicate the history of the old one, with corrected descriptions (but commit ID will be different, so it creates a lot of troubles if other people are working on the old branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I forgot to change the description of my new commit and accidentally pushed it without realizing that it was wrong. [...] Also, it's worthwhile to note that I have already moved on in my project, so the last commit is not the one with the mistake in it.

Looks like a job for [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

> I tried looking around for any buttons in both PyCharm and GitHub, but could not find anything.

Not surprised. Rebasing is too powerful a feature to work within the confines of any GUI that I've seen. It also can be a [footgun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footgun) for the uninitiated.

For this, you'll need to open a shell.

```bash
# We're going to replace some commits in this branch, and in order to do that,
# we first must switch to it.
git checkout <your branch>
# Note the "~" here -- it's necessary. It means "that commit ID, but the one
# before it"
git rebase -i <your commit id>~
# Then:
# 1. In the editor, change "pick" on the first line to "r" (reword)
# 2. Save-exit the file
# 3. The editor will immediately re-pop open with your commit message. Edit the
# commit message, then save-exit the file.
git rebase --continue
git push -f
```

This isn't recommended if you're part of a development team, but I've seen big open-source projects do it before.