# Git: ammened commit message won't reflect in git hub

Tags: git, github

I followed the instructions to fixing a pushed commit message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032374/accidentally-pushed-commit-change-git-commit-message). It worked well for my local repository. Then I force pushed it back to remote, but the old message is still on git hub. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong.

Edit:

https://github.com/crowelab/protocol-captures/commits/master

The second commit is the correct commit message. But when you click on it is still tied to the old commit message (everything is in there, everything is testes"

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the old commit still exists, even after force pushing a new commit (it's just not pointed to from `master` or `HEAD`). It sounds like you might be looking directly at the old commit. Remember that the new commit doesn't actually amend the old one, but creates a new one in place, with a different hash.

The right way to check is to check the recent commits at https://github.com/user/repo/commits/master

Comment: This one did reword the old commit, it did not make a new one. Check the link and you can actually use rebase to reword the commit with the same hash.

Comment: @jwillis0720 that is simply not true. Changing anything about a previous commit requires modifying the history and forcefully pushing the new version (thus breaking any other team members workflow). Check my suggestion before retorting.

Comment: check out the link, i'm still missing something

Comment: @jwillis0720, what do you feel is missing?