# Git change code from a specific pushed commit on specific branch

Tags: git, version-control

I still have some difficulties to understand completely the process to modified an already pushed commit.  
I am not working on the master branch (don't know if that matter), and I committed and pushed wrong data (say, clear password...) in the **Commit_2** (see below). 
I would like to change files from this commit only, and don't change the others. 
Of course, I have read the documentation git-rebase, cherry-pick etc.. as well as some very nice answers from SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032374/accidentally-pushed-commit-change-git-commit-message), but I am still not sure how to do it.

So, basically, how can I change files from, and only from **Commit_2** ?

> ```
> commit 54sdf4f4d5f4dsf4555q5aaaa44fr
> Author: me <me@me.com>
> Date:   Wed Sep 14 10:25:09 2016 +0200
>
>     Commit_3
>
> commit ghgzf4x1522qx1x5f222y4d
> Author: me <me@me.com>
> Date:   Tue Sep 13 15:01:42 2016 +0200
>
>     Commit_2
>
> commit dfsdc4ycx45ds4fyc6d4fysfsd
> Author: me <me@me.com>
> Date:   Tue Sep 13 14:57:08 2016 +0200
>
>      Commit_1
> ```

Comment: Change the password. If you've pushed it, it's been compromised by pushing. You can't uncompromise anything.

Comment: Private repo only shared with a little team, so not important. But want to make sure I can do it in case if it is really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to revert `Commit_2`, which would add a *new* commit which would completely undo the changes to every file modified in `Commit_2`.  This would be perfect if you wanted to remove all changes, but you want to retain *some* of the changes.

Run the following command to see which files were changed in `Commit_2`:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only dfsdc4yc
```

Now identify which files you want to *keep*, and then for each file type the following:

```
git checkout 54sdf4f4 file/to/restore
```

where `54sdf4f4` is the SHA-1 hash of `Commit_3`.  This will effectively redo everything which was done to files you want to keep.

Now you can commit this change.  You could amend the revert commit since you haven't yet pushed your local work, via:

```
git commit --amend -m 'Undo of certain files from Commit_2'
```

Comment: This is usually preferred, but I think the case of sanitizing a mistakenly committed password would require a rewrite, otherwise the password would still be available in history for others to exploit.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, mistakenly *pushed* password requires **CHANGING THAT PASSWORD**.

Answer (score 2):

I like interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i ghgzf4x1522qx1x5f222y4d^
```

Set that commit from `pick` to `e` for edit. Then make your changes (delete password). Then continue.

```
git rebase --continue
```

Now that you have rewritten history, you will have to force push to the remote.

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force
```

And others will need to non-fast-forward pull.

```
git fetch <remote>
git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>
```

Or maybe

```
git pull --rebase
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way to change anything in a commit**. Ever. The commit is identified by a sha1 checksum derived from all its content *and history*, so when you change anything, it will have a different sha1 and therefore be a different commit, and so will everything that follows it.

So the only thing you can do is *delete* the problematic commit from the repository and *replace* it with better version. You do that by force pushing (`git push -f`) a new version that does not contain it to every branch that did. You create that new version with `git commit --amend` (if it is the latest commit), `git rebase -i` (if it is not) or `git filter-branch` if it is deeper down the history.

However, if anybody already fetched that commit from the repository, **they get to keep it**. You can't stop them.

Comment: If i `git rebase -i [commit_id]`, do the changes and then `git push -f`, will I loose information from more recent commit?

Comment: @Mornor, you will replace all the commits that were part of that rebase with new versions that don't contain the information. But only the commits in that rebase - if there are any other commits based on the old commit, they remain based on the old commit.

Comment: He can `git revert` which will functionally undo the commit, though the original commit will still be there as you mentioned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, he can rewind and remove it even from history of all current heads, but since the information was ever there, it might have been already fetched and must be treated as compromised anyway.