# git says Everything up-to-date

Tags: linux, git, version-control

First of all, I am a noob at using git.

1. I was working on a project and did a commit and pushed to remote github repository.
2. But, then later I realized that I did some mistake, so I did $git --amend -am "My message"
3. Now, I was not able to push again to the remote server as I was getting error. So, I thought of deleting the remote github repo & recreated the same with the same name.
4. Now, when I try to push, it says "Everything up-to-date".

Please guide as to how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like two things have gone wrong, here.

First up, you amended a commit that had become part of the remote repository's history, which is a bit of a no-no. Rather than re-answer this gripe, I'll direct you to the answer: [How do I push amended commit to the remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)

Next, chances are that even though you re-created the remote repository, your local repository still has the local history from the old one. what you'll want to do is run `git remote rm origin`, then `git gc`, then `git remote add origin <path_to_repo>`, then finally `git fetch origin`. This should pick up the new remote repository, and allow you to push your changes to it.