# How do I delete *ALL* files and directories from a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on github and I need to complete reset it , i.e start uploading from scratch. How exactly do I remove all files and directories in the repository using git?

Comment: Why not just delete the repository itself and create a new one with the same name?

Comment: @robert thanks. I wonder why I didn't think of that. But anyway, I'll wait for an answer, there may be a good solution.

Comment: Any reason why just removing the files/dirs and committing that wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @robert you know what, just post a dramatically elaborated version of the above comment as the answer and I'll accept it if no other good answers come by that time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to take your local copy of the new repo, set it up as normal, then run `git push --force origin master` (or whatever you’ve named your remote and branch). This won’t actually *delete* all the files, directories and history (at least not immediately), but they will no longer be reachable from your head, which is all you need unless you really want to make it *impossible* to retrieve the existing files.