# Git : Head commit in remote repository is crap - how exactly should I go about replacing it?

Tags: git, push, commit

Alright - so I had a guy (in a school project - don't panic) commit a full eclipse workspace complete with .class files and .settings/ directories. ***What I did*** was to clone the repo and make a .gitignore file and issue :

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
$ ... unstaged all files and added .gitignore and all files that it filtered in ...
```

Then I tried :

```
 $ git commit -c d1cf2d8173234b444c601d5e294a5cf6d790fa2c
```

Where the SHA is the SHA of the online commit. It won't let me push :

> Pushing to https://USERNAME@git.assembla.com/PROJECT.git To
>   https://USERNAME@git.assembla.com/PROJECT.git  ! [rejected]
>   master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://USERNAME@git.assembla.com/PROJECT.git' To prevent you from
>   losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the
>   remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

My question is ***what should I have done instead ?***

So *how exactly should I go about deleting a commit in this scenario*. Do not warn me that it shouldn't be done - in this case it is very well acceptable, recommended and necessary to edit the history (I want to reclaim the space in the online repo). Also - I am not really worried how to force the push - I want the easier/cleaner way of ***replacing the remote HEAD commit with another***.

It all starts with a clone...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)

Comment: @CharlesBailey : not really a dup - I am not interested in amending - I just want to _completely replace_ the commit with a small part of the commited files + a .gitignore. Force does not work for some reason - which is the suggested route in question cited. Also I used `git commit -c <SHA of fluffy commit>` which is probably not the thing to do ?

Comment: It doesn't really whether you amend or wind back the branch and make a new commit, the fact is that you are trying to push a commit that is not a direct descendant of the remote branch. The problem that you facing is exactly the same as the problem in the question that I linked to.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yes I saw this - I could edit the question - what I really want to know is how I make the repo _forget_ about the fluffy commit and instead replace it with my commit. In short clone _then what ?_ The question linked is full of _don't do it_ and instructions of how to ammend your stupid messing up of history - and your answer details how to --force - but there is no clear account on how to actually do it -_saving the space in the repo_. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @CharlesBailey : please see the edited answer - and do unvote the close - the question linked is how one should push an amend - my question is how should one amend (without much fuss in pushing or otherwise)

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes.

Comment: @CharlesBailey : well ok - how about an answer then before this is closed :D

Comment: You won't get the space back until you purge all references to the unwanted commit(s) and force a garbage-collect.  This applies to all of the repos that contain the bad commit(s) (yours, your remote, any other clones of that remote).  In any case, no matter how you do it (with one commit as above, or with `git filter-branch` or `git rebase` etc) you'll need to get the remote repo to give you permission to push the non-fast-forward change.  Or, log in on the remote machine and do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from having to get the remote repo admins to allow you to rewind the "master" branch, see http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/ and in particular, the "cleanup and reclaiming space" section.

It's often simplest to start over with a new remote and have the remote-admins delete the old one entirely, in cases like yours. :-)

Comment: Thanks - but still my issue is how should I proceed _localy_ ? Clone then what ? Reset ? Amend ?

Comment: Do whatever you find easiest.  Since you only have one "bad" commit, `git commit --amend` will be pretty easy, and is probably how I would go, since you can repeat it as needed: `git rm -r this-definitely-goes and-that-too; git commit --amend -C HEAD; git show` ... oops, forgot one, repeat with missed part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the --force flag in your push statement, but it is risky if others are using the same repo.  Otherwise, you may want to update back to the remote head and use a Git revert.

Comment: Thanks a lot - no it's 2 people using it - and it's a pet project - so no harm done. I read that one should merge etc etc but I want to get rid of all the fluff uploaded - the repo has space limitations. Can you elaborate on the _update beck to the remote head and use a Git revert_ ?

Comment: Failed !: `$ git push -f
Password for 'https://USER@git.assembla.com':
Counting objects: 102, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (101/101), 1.65 MiB | 28 KiB/s, done.
Total 101 (delta 8), reused 64 (delta 5)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To https://USER@git.assembla.com/REPO.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://USER@git.assembla.com/REPO.git'`

Comment: try `git push --force remote branch`

Comment: `remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To https://regar@git.assembla.com/texlogismikou2012.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://USER@git.assembla.com/REPO.git'
fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument`  -- maybe another approach ? reclone and ...

Comment: That's weird that it's rejecting a force. There are a few ways to do this. You may want to Google git revert to see if that helps. Otherwise, yes, a new clone > commit changes > push will work.

Comment: A new clone and commit will certainly work but I want to make git to completely forget about all the binary crap in the repo. Can you elaborate on revert ?

Comment: Presumably the remote has `receive.denyNonFastForwards` set in its config: "receive.denyNonFastForwards
    If set to true, git-receive-pack will deny a ref update which is not a fast-forward. Use this to prevent such an update via a push, even if that push is forced. This configuration variable is set when initializing a shared repository. "

Comment: @torek:It does indeed - and it appears (assembla) that I have to go through the moderators to change this setting. Anyway my question is what is the best way to achieve what I want - push aside.