# GIT wont push after initial commit

Tags: git, netbeans

I'm trying to setup a shared repository for a project I'm working on for work. I'm still fairly new to this as my work never really used any source control before now.
We're trying to setup a shared git repository. After the initial commit is made no other user can push any changes. Only the user who made the initial commit is capable of making any changes. Others can pull and clone, but not push.

I'm initializing the shared repository with:

```
git init --bare project.git
```

After the initial commit, other users when pushing from netbeans get the error:

```
REJECTED_OTHER_REASON
```

Which quite frankly isn't very helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you all on the same branch? Have you tried the `--force` switch? Also, isn't that a filesystem privilege issue? How do you host your repo?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275121/6309 help?

Comment: Yes, we only have the one master branch, so that shouldn't be an issue. Pushing through netbeans doesn't give us the option to use the --force switch. We're using CopSSH to host the repo, and I think it might be a permission issue but when I tried giving the User group ownership nothing changed.

Comment: @VonC It would if netbeans gave the option to use switches, but I can't find away to add --force.

Answer (score 0):

On your server try running:

```
git update-server-info
```