# Git push failed after 'git reset --hard HEAD~1' of local repo

Tags: git

I have a local git repo on my workstation which I push to a dropbox location so that I can pull it down to my laptop via `git pull remote dropbox`.

Yesterday I checked in a change on my workstation, committed it and `git push dropbox`'ed it.  I did not do a `git pull` from my laptop because I suspected that I was going to end up throwing that commit away.

Today I decided to throw that commit away, so on my workstation I did:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

So far, so good.  Now I want to push this back up to Dropbox, so that on my laptop I can merge and commit from *there*.  So on my workstation I tried:

```
git push dropbox
```

And git complained that:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
>   to push some refs to '\My Dropbox\dev\repos\xcast.git' To prevent you
>   from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the
>   remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

How do I get my worstation and Dropbox back in sync again?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Force push should work: `git push -f dropbox`

Git is complaining because your remote still has that extra commit, and thus you are behind it in terms of history.

Comment: Are there any negative repercussions of doing this?

Comment: @Grunch: yes, you lose the commit in the remote. If you've shared that commit with anyone else, histories may diverge.

Comment: @Grunch Yeah, only ever force push if you're sure no one has already pulled the changes (or you're the only one with access)

Comment: @larsmans:  The remote is shared among all my own computers.  I did not do a pull from the remote on any of those other machines since yesterday's ill-fated commit.  Does that mean that in this case, histories will not diverge?

Comment: @Grunch You should be fine if they haven't pulled yet.

Comment: @Grunch Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo/255080#255080

Comment: @jli:  Great, thanks.  Once I do this and try to do a pull from the remote on my laptop, should I expect git to say "already up to date"?

Comment: @Grunch Yeah that should be the case.