# git rebase develop branch

Tags: git

Sorry, just another "rebase" question but I'm confused about that.
Form time to time I push my commits on the develop branch to remote (origin). Now one thing always mentioned with rebase is: "never rebase if you have pushed your changes".
This means, I could never ever rebase my develop branch, only merge it?

Working on a feature-branch is clear, if I haven't pushed that, I could rebase instead of merge. My question only points to the develop branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read ["The Perils of Rebase" in the "Pro Git" book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing) — it provides nice explanation with pictures. The [`git-rebase` manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) also contains the section "Recovering from upstream rebase") which makes you appear in the shoes of everyone who might be affected by your rebase. ;-) Nice ASCII-art is included as well.

And no, "never rebase what was pushed to a public repo" should not be taken as a dogma: sometimes, it's a valid approach, *if such rebasing is clearly articulated to other users of your public repository.* For instance, see [what the current Git maintainer says about his "pu" branch](http://lwn.net/Articles/145124/) (this memo is somewhat outdated, and newer versions of this text do not mention rebasing directly, so I decided to link to this older copy).

Comment: I've read the "Pro Git" book and it seams to be clear in my mind when I work on a feature branch. But in fact, "develop" is just a branch like all others with the same rules. So any branch pushed to a remote-repo should not be rebased. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

2012: You can rebase (and force the next push) provided nobody has cloned/updated his/her own local repo with your remote repo.
If other people have pulled from your remote repo, and you force push your rebased branch, you publish a new history, forcing them to a more complex operation of reset (they have to reset their own local branch to the new remote branch history, and then reapply their own commits).
For a public remote repo, a [forced push can lead to problems ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo#432518).

---

2023: as noted by [bbaassssiiee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571517/bbaassssiiee), `git push --force-with-lease` can mitigate the issue, although:

- it was introduced with Git v1.8.5, Dec. 2023, a year after this answer.
- as [I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309), it is not always safe. The [`git push --force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309) can also help (Git 2.30, Q1 2021).

Comment: `git push --force-with-lease` addresses that issue.

Comment: @bbaassssiiee Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with some additional references.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what "kind" of branch you have (after all it's just a concept, for git, a branch is a branch). Once you pushed any changes, don't do a rebase, otherwise the hash of the commit will change.

Comment: You mean: "It does not matter ...". That's right, "develop" is just a name for another branch. Got to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rebase the pushed commits. However, it's perfectly fine to rebase (`-i`) commits that have not been pushed.