# How to push the amended commit message to remote

Tags: git, message, commit, git-push

I followed this thread on [how to amend the commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git).

It went well. But in the previous commit I pushed the updates to remote as well. Now once I changed the commit message, its rejecting the remote push. It says `filed to push refs`.

I tried the commmand from one of the comments in the above thread.

```
git push -f origin branchname
```

It does not seem to be working either.
Any other ideas? If its not working, I want to rollback the amended commit message to original.

Comment: I found the answer on this thread.  [How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?][1]. If something changed since then, or if something simpler can be done, please answer.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo?rq=1

Comment: Can you write the message that `git push -f origin branchname` returns?