# Git prevents pushing after amending a commit

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit, git-amend

Usually, I just run

```
git add file
git commit
git push
```

but if I amend the commit **before** pushing it (with `git commit --amend`), the next push fails with

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I let git push the changes without merging branches? I only have one branch (`master`) and I'm the only person using this repo so why is it saying this?

git branch -a:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

EDIT: Using `gitk HEAD @{u}`, I see that I have 2 branches, one with the original commit and another with the amended commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)

Comment: @Deebster The question you linked was about amending a commit already pushed to the remote, I'm amending a commit which hasn't been pushed yet.

Comment: `I only have one branch (master) and I'm the only person using this repo`  and `I see that I have 2 branches, one with the original commit and another with the amended commit.` Its conflicting, can you please explain what you exactly did

Comment: `git add file`
`git commit -m "something"`
`git commit -m "something else"` would work fine

Comment: @Sagar It looks like the amendment has been created as a new branch and the original commit is in `master`. I haven't made a new branch myself

Comment: No amend wont create any branch. Whats the output of `git branch -a` ?

Comment: @Sagar Added output to my question

Comment: The problem appears to have fixed itself. I thank everyone who contributed for their time and effort. It was likely fixed by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/2734389)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This should only be the case if you're amending an already-pushed commit. Generally you should never do that as you're then modifying published history. In your case however, you should be able to get away with `push -f`, which will overwrite the remote commit with your amended revision.

Comment: Can't thank @joey enough, that was the exact reason why I wasted the last few minutes, and yes it did resolve the issue.

Comment: BEWARE - if not used with caution `git push -f <remote> <branch>` can overwrite your commit history.  Leaving no way for you to revert commit if something goes wrong.

Comment: @markroxor yes. don't must use -f command. Because overwrite all previous commits. This is destroyer.

Comment: I also mistakenly ammend'ed after a push. @markroxor can you provide a workaround then, if -f is a bad solution? This would be extra helpful.

Comment: "Leaving no way for you to revert commit if something goes wrong." Find someone who has not pulled from remote. :/

Comment: @markroxor Or pull yourself again in some other location.

Answer (score 33):

Yup, you should not do that (pushing a commit, then changing it and trying to push it again).

Instead, you can roll back Git to your previous commit without changing the files, then creating a new commit:

```
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add .
git commit -m "This is a new commit for what I originally planned to be an amendmend"
git push origin master
```

this will create a new commit with the changes you were about to amend.

Comment: But I've ran `git commit --amend` before running `git push` in the first place

Comment: was there any pushed commit in the remote, before you experienced the problem?

Comment: thanks a lot. git pull was not working for me, but git reset --mixed origin/master got it working.

Comment: This should be the better answer. The accepted one can be destructive. This is better. Thank you.

Comment: if your organisation has modified your rights, then the best answer with -f might not work. So this answer was better in my case.

Answer (score 10):

you amended the pulled commit as in

```
git pull origin master
git commit -a --amend -m "..."
git push
```

you can solve the issue by reverting the amended commit:

```
git reset --mixed origin/master
```

and then making it again as a full fledged commit

Comment: What do you mean? I've amended it before pushing the changes

Answer (score 0):

if you use a code creater like viusal code : you have to do https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5cKP.png

then :
you can do whatever git push or git pull